# How to unit-test code depending on a complex graph database interaction

Tags: python, unit-testing, neo4j, architecture, cypher

I'm developing a **Python** app based on [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/), and I'm facing a challenge to write unit-tests in isolation from the Neo4j database, so I can run my unit-tests without depending on starting a full-blown database.

The Neo4j **Java** SDK includes an ["In-Memory / Impermanent database"](http://javadox.com/com.github.jasoma/neo4j-memorydb/3.1.1/org/neo4j/test/TestGraphDatabaseFactory.html)

Unfortunately, the [Python driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/) doesn't have that.

## Ideas

### Mocks

I considered mocking the database, however you [shouldn't mock what you don't own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own).
Especially third-party libraries.

As I want my unit-test to be reliable and follow a good design, I don't want to follow this path.

### Ports and Adapters

From a software architecture standpoint, integrating a third-party library like Neo4j should be done following the Ports and Adapters pattern.
This will give me the following benefits

- decouple my business logic from the graph logic
- have a clearly defined contract (port) that adapters have to implement
- having a Fake Neo4j adapter implementation, to be passed to my business logic for unit tests

This is promising, but I'm overwhelmed by the amount of code to write.

Example code with the official Neo4j driver

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687")
with driver.session() as session:
    query = """MATCH (u:USER)
             WHERE u.name = $name
             RETURN u"""
    cursor = session.run(query, parameters={'name', 'Alfred'})
    for result in cursor:
        acc_type = result['u']['account_type']
        return acc_type
```

Example "Ports and Adapters" implementation

Defining the API (Port)

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractGraphService(ABC):
    def __init__(url: str):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def __enter__():
        """returns a session"""
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def __exit__(*args):
        """close session object"""
        pass


class AbstractSession(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, query, parameters):
        """execute a cypher query"""
        pass
```

➡️ how can I write a fake, in-memory implementation ? Am I supposed to write a Fake Cypher-execution engine as well ?

➡️ with the API demonstrated above, I haven't decoupled my Cypher queries from my business logic code

➡️ Is there a better road to follow to unit-test my code ?

Thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You could have separate Python functions for connecting to the database, querying it and processing the return. For the latter the Python pandas package has a nice capability. use this, where Q is your cypher query and Neo4jServer might be remote or local as in Neo4Server ="bolt://{IP or localhost}:7687". If you're using Neo4j 4.x, you need to specify the specific database.

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from pandas import DataFrame

def CypherToPandas(Q, database):
    driver=GraphDatabase.driver(Neo4Server, auth=(Neo4UserName,Neo4Pswd),database=database ) 
    with driver.session(database=database) as cyphersession:
        rslt = cyphersession.run(Q)
        df = DataFrame(rslt.data())
        cyphersession.close()
        driver.close()
        return df
```

I have a variety of functions that can be repurposed for a variety of uses. The Neo4j code is separate from the business logic. You can then run the unit tests and, when tested, seamlessly incorporate them into your solution.